# Can I allow the cursor to reach between screens?

Tags: macos, display

I have a mac laptop. At work, I have 2 extra monitors I'm using. One is set above the laptop, the other is to the right side. See image below for my configuration of monitors.

[image: Displays]

My issue is that I can't move my cursor from top monitor's top right corner over to the right monitor in a straight line. You can see there is obviously a gap. I am forced to go around that corner where they intersect. Is there a way to allow my cursor to move in the "whitespace" between the monitors, or to configure the area that the cursor can move? Ideally, I would like to be able to use a square area that is as tall as my monitors and as wide as my monitors so that I can move between them without getting caught on edges.

I am on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Without the use of a third-party app, if one even exists, then no, you have to move the mouse from one screen to the next within the adjacent edges.

Comment: @user3439894 sounds like an answer if I ever heard one

Answer (score 2):

Without the use of a third-party app, if one even exists, then no, you have to move the mouse from one screen to the next within the adjacent edges.